# (70007)The timeout specified has expired on apache 2.4 php-fpm

Tags: php, apache

I set up a new webserver with PHP-FPM, mod_proxy_fcgi and got timeout errors (Gateway 504)!
Using Liveconfig to manage the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server.

I use a mysql database just 23 Mio entries, NVME, PHP 7.2 script...sometimes it needs some time to find all entries of a user the script sometimes have to pick 150.000 entries out of 23 Mio. I tried mod_apache, this works without problems but is not secure for me

I setting up max_execution time to "0" on PHP also i tried some solutions on the web but they often dont work for apache2 or they not practicable for Ubuntu 18.04 i.e.

Try to find a way to set a proxy_timeout, dont know where in apache2 and config from liveconfig. This settings set liveconfig on host config.

````
     <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
         SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm/web0.sock|fcgi://localhost"
         SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
     </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule>

[Wed Nov 06 06:36:13.067278 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22899:tid 139849199208192] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87.133.62.232:52647] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https:/xxxxxxxxx?filter=true&sid=vs9r2kbc1qgvadu9jhajcitb7u
[Wed Nov 06 06:36:16.826764 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22899:tid 139849249613568] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87.133.62.232:52647] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https:/xxxxxxxxx?filter=true&sid=hb4gv5kappll0gs82r18bh40oj
[Wed Nov 06 06:37:36.236112 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22899:tid 139849266415360] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87.133.62.232:52647] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https:/xxxxxxxxxlfqvcuu
[Wed Nov 06 06:38:34.683775 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22899:tid 139849224410880] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87.133.62.232:52647] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https:/xxxxxxxxx?filter=true&sid=rvai9hl8d0nu4blnotbpq2hf2p
[Wed Nov 06 06:45:24.902575 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22899:tid 139849375627008] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87.133.62.232:52647] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https:/xxxxxxxxx?filter=true&sid=vs9r2kbc1qgvadu9jhajcitb7u
[Wed Nov 06 06:56:39.785049 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22899:tid 139849375627008] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 87.133.62.232:52647] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https:/xxxxxxxxx?filter=true&sid=hb4gv5kappll0gs82r18bh40oj```
````

Comment: Please post your complete PHP.ini and the MySQL my.cnf files.